# Retrieve an image and load it in a html page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am working with php and ajax. I'm able to retrive an image from a database, but I would like to show the image in 100px x 100px size, but it just retrieves the original image size and spoiling the aligning work that I did.

How can I fix the width and height for a retrieved image. I have used the following code for retriving from database

```
$query = "select bin_data from imageupload where Id=1;";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
$result_data = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg") ;
echo $result_data['bin_data'];
```

Comment: While retriving from database itself, i would like to resize the image according to the requirement

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps this code performs

1. Copies source image
2. Calculates image dimensions
3. Resizes image (you specify max height/width)
4. Retains aspect ratio
5. Writes destination image

   ---

This was created from a variety of code snippets 
I've found here at php.net and other places on the web.
I take no credit for any of this code other than 
putting the pieces together. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

```
    <?php

$source_pic = 'images/source.jpg';
$destination_pic = 'images/destination.jpg';
$max_width = 500;
$max_height = 500;

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_pic);
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($source_pic);

$x_ratio = $max_width / $width;
$y_ratio = $max_height / $height;

if( ($width <= $max_width) && ($height <= $max_height) ){
    $tn_width = $width;
    $tn_height = $height;
    }elseif (($x_ratio * $height) < $max_height){
        $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
        $tn_width = $max_width;
    }else{
        $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
        $tn_height = $max_height;
}

$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($tn_width,$tn_height);
imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$tn_width, $tn_height,$width,$height);

imagejpeg($tmp,$destination_pic,100);
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resize an image is CPU intensive for the server, if bandwith is not a problem:

```
<img src="theimage.jpg" style="width:100px; height:100px;" />
```

Modern browsers filters the image so it looks good when resized.

It you want to keep aspect ratio and crop, do this:

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden; display:inline-block;">
  <img src="theimage.jpg" style="width:100px;" />
</div>
```

Also consider using Pasta's answer plus an image cache. To resize only once every picture without loosing the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `gd` module to do this. See the [`imagecopyresampled`](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) function and the examples in it's documentation.

Note that this is an expensive operation, so you should either save a resized image when it's uploaded or cache the result.